# What percent of votes do you think are actually correct?

Tags: discussion

Roughly what percent of votes, on philosophy.stackexchange, up down or to close, do you think are actually correct?

I'm guessing about 1/2.

As an example of incorrect voting e.g. I have [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39885/what-is-philosophy-for?noredirect=1#comment97942_39885), which I asked yesterday and has 4 downvotes. The question is researched, clear, and could be helpful to any number of people. The voters are *mistaken*.

Comment: What do you mean by correct? Also, your last sentence is ungrammatical, did you mean "that"? And how is this different from your previous question?

Comment: it's different because it's a completely different question, just with similar concerns. by correct i mean that the question *really is* e.g. unclear @Keelan

Comment: @Keelan also your responses pretty miuch demonstrate the fact you're feigning confusion all the time, probably something petty

Comment: I am not feigning confusion. On what grounds do you guess 1/3? What can we do more with this question than random guessing?

Comment: if you're "not feiging confusion" why are you asking if this is the same question as a question that you think is about whether or not all downvotes are bad? @Keelan

Comment: I am not sure whether they are the same because both are unclear. Since it seems to be the same discussion, the questions can possibly be merged.

Comment: "What can we do more with this question than random guessing?" you could, as well as guess, suggest a remedy or that there isn't one @Keelan

Comment: @Keelan i've already explained that they're not the same question

Comment: You don't ask for a remedy. If that is what you are looking for, you should ask for it. But then you should also make it agreeable that there actually is a problem, ideally with examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50644/discussion-between-mathemetician-and-camil-staps).

Comment: @Keelan hey man, sorry for being a pig. i'll delete my accout when i can. again, apologies man :)

Answer (score 1):

The tool tip for the "vote up" arrow for questions says:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

and for "vote down":

> "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

"not useful" can mean a lot of things. A natural interpretation would be that this is a question which does not work well in the format of this site.

The [example you give](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39885/what-is-philosophy-for) is a *super-broad* question, there is a whole field about that, meta-philosophy. So wouldn't it be better to read an introductory book instead of asking here? At *best* you get a nice summary of meta-philosophy.

I guess 70%-80% of votes are "correct" here.

I think that it is more likely for up-votes to be incorrect, though. For example it is completely incomprehensible to me why [such a question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39933/where-can-i-learn-mathematical-logic) gets five up-votes. But if we are not envious, we can ignore incorrect up-votes. Incorrect down-votes are more problematic.

There are interesting questions which are clear, useful and show research effort, but sound a bit complaining/belligerent or poetic/pompous. Those tend to get, in my view, down-voted *incorrectly* a lot.

Also questions which are about something in the "transition zone" between philosophy and the specialized "science" (in the broad sense), i.e. *philosophical* questions *about* mathematics which look just like mathematical questions, tend, in my view, attract a lot of incorrect down-votes and even close-votes.

For example, I think that [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21325/can-we-add-pi-to-pi) wasn't *such* a bad question. Would have never down-voted or voted to close it.

There also seems to be a tendency to deal out down-votes more readily because of clumsy writing style, spelling and grammar mistakes, which is sad, because like me many users are not native English speakers.

Still, I must admit that I down-vote a lot more on philosophy.SE compared to other sub-communities. But this is also a problem of the *answers*. There are a lot of *bad* answers here, which in my view get down-voted nearly always *correctly.*

Because contrary to the stereotype of the elitism of philosophy, the layman can easily suffer from the illusion that he is able to understand technical philosophical questions.

If you ask on math.SE [*"Why are vector spaces not isomorphic to their duals?"*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/why-are-vector-spaces-not-isomorphic-to-their-duals) you will probably not get very bad answers. Because the uninformed user doesn't even know what *duals* or *isomorphic* means. If you understand these terms, you had *some* "higher" math education and not give a very bad answer.

But if you ask on philosophy.SE *"What is the difference between not true and false?",* you'll might get bogus answers like [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/38542/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-not-true-and-false/38543#38543).

Comment: i don't know of anything which analyses different ideas about the aims of philosophy. it's a fairly broad question, but as you say not unanswerable

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN no, as said, metaphilosophy does analyze what philosophy is *for,* there are different schools, one of the more pessimistic one would be quietism. And, yes, your question is not unanswerable, of course. But aside from being very broad, it's kind of duplicateish, see [this question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/how-will-learning-about-philosophy-impact-real-life) for example.

Comment: i fail to see any real duplication there but if it's too broad that's your judgement to make, as someone who may be able to answer it